# Access Extended Choice Parameter Script plugin parameters in Groovy script

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I used [Extended Choice Parameter Script plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+Script+plugin) and created a JSON editor with Array type as below:

```
disable_edit_json: true,
disable_properties: true,
disable_collapse: true,
theme: "jqueryui",
iconlib:"fontawesome4",
schema: {
    "type": "object",
    "title": "instances",
    "properties": {
        "instance": {
            "type": "array",
            "propertyOrder" : 1,
            "format": "table",
            "uniqueItems": true,
            "items": {
                "title": "instance",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "url": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The parameter name is "ServerUrls". Using this I can pass one or many URLs to my Jenkins job, and I want to know the size of the array and access each of these parameter values from within a Groovy script. Conceptually something like ServerUrls.instance[0], ServerUrls.instance[1](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+Script+plugin) etc.

Just doing `println params["ServerUrls"]` throws an Exception.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked. The solution is as below, and it returns the value as JSON in a string format. It should be fairly easy to parse the JSON to obtain the internals of it.

```
def hardcoded_param = "ServerUrls"
def resolver = build.buildVariableResolver
def hardcoded_param_value = resolver.resolve(hardcoded_param)

println hardcoded_param_value
```